# log transformation for geom_histogram and stat_function

Tags: lognormal-distribution, ggplot2

I am playing around with lognormally distributed data, and I would like to visualize it both on the original and log scale with ggplot

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0.01,10)), aes(x=x)) +
geom_histogram(data=tibble(x=rlnorm(1000)), aes(x=x, y=..density..)) +
stat_function(fun=stats::dlnorm, aes(color="LogNormal") )
```

[image]
this makes the histogram from simulated data and draws the lognormal distribution on the original scale. But when I convert it to log the graphs seem way off. What am I missing?

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(0.01,10)), aes(x=x)) +
geom_histogram(data=tibble(x=rlnorm(1000)), aes(x=x, y=..density..)) +
stat_function(fun=stats::dlnorm, aes(color="LogNormal") ) +
scale_x_continuous(trans='log')
```

[image]

Comment: I don't follow the code, but perhaps one of them uses log base 10 and the other uses log base e (natural log)?

Comment: @mkt both are formulated from base e, as you can see from the first graph, the default parameters are meanlog=0, sdlog=1 (the graphs look ok for these parameters). And the argument converting then to log is common (the `scale_x_continuous(trans='log')` bit)...

Comment: I'll take your word for it. I meant that log10(e) is approximately 0.4, and the red curve might peak at that value, which would help diagnose the problem if true.

Comment: thanks your right log10(e) is 0.4! I think ggplot is first changing the axis to log and then drawing the dlnorm function on top. Don't know how to get around this though.

Comment: That might be a good question for stackoverflow - coding questions are off-topic here, I'm afraid. But the easiest solution is to do the calculations first and just use ggplot2 for plotting the output, instead of asking ggplot2 (or base graphics) to do the log-transformation for you.

Answer (score 1):

(Turning my comments into an answer, since it seems to have found the problem)

log10(e) is approximately 0.43, and the red curve looks like it peaks at about that value. If true, it suggests that the sequence of ggplot2's actions is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@mkt Thanks for your comments. I found [almost the exact same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137824/ggplot-scale-transformation-inaccurate-for-stat-function) in stackoverflow as you suggested. The key is to use 'dnorm' instead of 'dlnorm' for the log transformed data. So for example this would work (with the default mean=0, sd=0, meanlog=0, meansd=1)

ggplot() +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=log(x), y=..density..), bins=100,
                   data=tibble(x=rlnorm(1000))) +
    stat_function(data=data.frame(x=seq(-5,5,0.1)), 
                  fun=dnorm)

[image]